# ssh tunnel between two servers with keys

Tags: linux, ssh, scp, tunnel

I have two servers, A and B, using two different keys. I work on server A, and need to transfer files to server B. But I have trouble transfer the files, because of the server connection refused when I tried the following ssh tunnel;

From server A:

```
ssh -L 1234:server_B:22 -p 45678 user_in_A@server_A
```

then there it seems to pause, and after a while the connection expires.

if I scp normally with my key as following, then i manage to transfer my files across, so I combine the codes i use in scp and ssh.

```
ssh -i key -L 1234:server_B:22 -p 45678 user_in_A@server_A
```

but it didn't work.

Before I did this, I googled either there is a way to do that. But most of the answers and explanations seem to lead to the `ssh -L ...` with no key, so what have i missed here? maybe a concept I haven't grasped or I am way off my mark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If server A can establish a TCP connection to port 22 of server B, and you are entering those commands in server A, then the tunnel is unnecessary.

```
ssh -L 1234:server_B:22 -p 45678 user_in_A@server_A
```

If you're running thes command **on server A**, it means:

- you're expecting server A to have `sshd` in port 45678
- you're making a SSH connection from server A to user_in_A@server_A
- you're also setting up a tunnel from server A's port 1234 to server B's port 22, i.e. server A's `sshd` will be setting up a TCP proxy in port 1234 on server A, and forwarding the connection(s) to it into port 22 of server B.

Since the SSH connection is from server A to server A, the encrypted part of the tunnel will be entirely within server A, and so pretty much useless. If the tunnel works, it means you can simply use `scp` to transfer files without making the tunnel:

```
scp -i key_for_user_in_B /some/where/local/files user_in_B@server_B:
```

or

```
scp -i key_for_user_in_B user_in_B@server_B:/some/remote/path /some/local/path/
```

The first will "push" files from local (A) to B, the second will "pull" files from B to local (A).